# Is having a letter "z" in your (short) domain a bad idea?

Tags: domains, usability

I recently found [this post posted by WhoAPI in 2013](https://whoapi.com/blog/1413/we-are-out-of-4-letter-com-domains/) and as you scroll down, at the bottom you'll find a section talking a part about letters in the domain:

> It goes so far that there is a general consensus among domainers, and
>   letter frequency statistics also indicate, that there are premium
>   letters, average letters, and bad letters.
>
> - Premium letters: a b c d e f g h i l m n o p r s t
> - Average letters: j k u v w
> - Bad letters: q x y z

With this paragraph above in mind, does it still work for a **5 letter .com domain**?

Someone has told me that if the `z` is in a dictionary word (e.g. `zero(.)com`) it'll still be valuable, but how about it's in a abbreviation (e.g. `John and David's Technology discussing zone` -> `jdtdz(.)com`)?

**So will a 5 letter domain which is a abbreviation of a long word worth it to register and use as your own domain?**

P.S. I'm not buying to sell, I'm buying for own use.

Comment: xkcd.com is one of the most popular 4L domains.  That x doesn't seem to hurt it.  It may even make it more memorable.

Comment: Please post or comment the reasoning behind this claims. Maybe the claims don't make much sense if they aren't properly justified.

Comment: @Osvaldo I just find a 5L domain but I want to make a decision should I end it with p or z which stand for protocol or zone. Since they said z is a bad letter I want to know does it really matters on user feeling or will it makes user less likely to visit?

Comment: The article you read was non-sense unfounded horse raddish. Domain names can be any size, any word(s), any non-word(s), any misspelling mistake(s) and still rank fine. The only exception is adult words and long exact domain matches.

Comment: You are going to read all kinds of crazy stuff on the net. The link you provided is just one example. Do not freak out and think these people are a swami. On the contrary. The web is simple stuff. Do not pay attention to folks who complicate things too much. Keep it simple. Cheers!!

Comment: I think that the article should have used "less popular" instead of "bad".   There is nothing bad about those letters.   They just aren't used in as many words meaning that most domain names containing them are less valuable and less likely to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So will a 5 letter domain which is a abbreviation of a long word worth it to register and use as your own domain?

No. Well maybe a yes if its a well known abbreviation, but you want to cater your website to your users so you want your domain name to be something people will likely type in when they want to access your website manually.

For example:

If you're doing a site about fancy cars, then a nice domain would be:

```
fancycars.com
```

However, don't use this domain:

```
fc.com
```

because people wouldn't even think F would stand for fancy and C would stand for cars.

By putting in the most important keyword of your site right in the domain name itself, you might get a boost in search engines.

Comment: Agreed. There is no semantic value in fc as you use in your example whereas fancycars would contain semantic value. This semantic value allows the domain to weigh for search terms where it applies. Cheers!!

Comment: Good answer for short v.s. long domain, although it's quite off-topic against the bad letters